# dlopen() - Is this undefined symbol error related to dependencies?

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, reverse-engineering, undefined-symbol

The background of the issue is in an already answered question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547182/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-particular-c-function-symbol-as-output-by-nm)

I have a symbol that I want to use in a shared library but despite being listed as a `T` defined symbol via `nm`, `F` (function) via `objdump`, when I try to access it using dlopen() or via Python (`ctypes.CDLL`), it seemingly does not exist or is not defined.

I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623873/accessing-so-libraries-using-dlopen-throws-undefined-symbol-error) that this could be related to dependencies.

Output of `ldd`:

```
linux@host:~$ ldd ./compiled_program
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffde1fdf000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3381e7c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f338246f000)
```

Output of `dn -DC`:

```
linux@host:~$ nm -DC ./compiled_program
             w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
             w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
             w __cxa_finalize
             w __gmon_start__
             U __libc_start_main
             U __stack_chk_fail
             U printf
             U putchar
             U puts
             U rand
             U srand
             U time
```

With my limited knowlege of C, I am unable to tell if any of these might be unresolved dependencies and where to look for which libraries to load, as the answer suggests, to include them. Is it as simple as finding the library and adding an `#include <...>` or do I have to locate the library and load it with `dlopen()`? The answer seems to suggest the latter. I appreciate that I am completely flailing in the dark here!

My current dlopen code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void *handle;
    void (*func_in_question)(const char*);
    handle = dlopen("./compiled_program", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        /* fail to load the library */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    *(void**)(&func_in_question) = dlsym(handle, "function_I_would_like_to_use");
    if (!func_in_question) {
        /* no such symbol */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    func_in_question(argv[1]);
    dlclose(handle);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

comes back with the undefined symbol error.

I would be grateful for any pointers on, a) any other reasons why I might not be able to access this symbol?
and b) if my half-baked suspicion about dependencies is anywhere near to making sense!

**EDIT:** copying error message from original question linked above:

> `Error: ./compiled_program: undefined symbol: function_I_would_like_to_use`

and the output of `nm --defined-only ./compiled_program` from original
question:

> ```
>     0000000000200d98 d _DYNAMIC
>     0000000000200f88 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
>     0000000000000ba0 R _IO_stdin_used
>     0000000000000d64 r __FRAME_END__
>     0000000000000bfc r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
>     0000000000201010 D __TMC_END__
>     0000000000201010 B __bss_start
>     0000000000201000 D __data_start
>     00000000000007d0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
>     0000000000200d90 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
>     0000000000201008 D __dso_handle
>     0000000000200d88 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
>     0000000000200d90 t __init_array_end
>     0000000000200d88 t __init_array_start
>     0000000000000b90 T __libc_csu_fini
>     0000000000000b20 T __libc_csu_init
>     0000000000201010 D _edata
>     0000000000201018 B _end
>     0000000000000b94 T _fini
>     0000000000000660 T _init
>     0000000000000710 T _start
>     0000000000201010 b completed.7696
>     0000000000201000 W data_start
>     0000000000000740 t deregister_tm_clones
>     0000000000000810 t frame_dummy
>     0000000000000a92 T main
>     000000000000081a T function_I_would_like_to_use                 \\ << this one
>     0000000000000780 t register_tm_clones
> ```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full error message

Comment: `Error: ./compiled_file: undefined symbol: function_I_would_like_to_use`

Comment: Is `compiled_program` a dynamic, shared object?

Comment: I doubt whether this has anything to do with dependencies. But I note that you have no clear idea about which call failed. I'd suggest changing your error format strings to make this clear: one should be  `"Error in dlopen: %s\n"` and the other `"Error in dlsym: %s\n"`, or something like that.

Comment: @stark, yes I believe so according to output of `file`: `./compiled_file: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=cf62f3afa6f99f98a863d44932d2e
0f9f8594e71, not stripped`

@rici, thanks for the tip but the error is "undefined symbol" and mentions the symbol called in dlsym, so it must have been that.

Comment: Use `extern "C"` when you define your functions. (A note about C++: it doesn't work well together with $X -- In this case X=dlopen/dlsym)